# Sum and Group by in linq using Datarows

Tags: c#, linq

Full disclosure, I'm pretty much a total noob whe it comes to linq. I could be way of base on how i should be approaching this.

I have a `DataTable` with 3 columns

oid,idate,amount

each id has multiple dates, and each date has multiple amounts. What I need to do is sum the amount for each day for each id, so instead of:

- id,date,amount

  - 00045,02/13/2011,11.50
  - 00045,02/14/2011,11.00
  - 00045,02/14/2011,12.00
  - 00045,02/15/2011,10.00
  - 00045,02/15/2011,5.00
  - 00045,02/15/2011,12.00
  - 00054,02/13/2011,8.00
  - 00054,02/13/2011,9.00

I would have:

- id,date,SumOfAmounts

  - 00045,02/13/2011,11.50
  - 00045,02/14/2011,23.00
  - 00045,02/15/2011,27.00
  - 00054,02/13/2011,17.00

---

```
private void excelDaily_Copy_Into(DataTable copyFrom, DataTable copyTo)
{
    var results = from row in copyFrom.AsEnumerable()
    group row by new
    {
        oid = row["oid"],
        idate = row["idate"]
    } into n
    select new
    {
    ///unsure what to do
    }
};
```

I've tried a dozen or so different ways of doing this and I always sort of hit a wall where i can't figure out how to progress. I've been all over stack overflow and the msdn and nothing so far has really helped me.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try this:

```
var results = from row in copyFrom.AsEnumerable()
              group row by new
              {
                oid = row.Field<int>("oid"),// Or string, depending what is the real type of your column
                idate = row.Field<DateTime>("idate")
              } into g
              select new
              {
                 g.Key.oid,
                 g.Key.idate,
                 SumOfAmounts=g.Sum(e=>e.Field<decimal>("amount"));
              };
```

I suggest to use [Field](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowextensions.field?view=net-6.0) extension method which provides strongly-typed access to each of the column values in the specified row.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I needed. So if I wanted to order it by the oid and then the date i would do an orderby just before the select new.

Edit:Sorry, didn't realize it was mini-Markdown.

Comment: An easy way can be doing this: `result=result.OrderBy(e=>new{e.oid,e.idate});`

Answer (score 1):

Although you don't specify it, apparently copyFrom is an object from a class DataTable that implements IEnumerable.

According to [MSDN System.Data.DataTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable(v=vs.110).aspx) the class does not implement it. If you use that class, you need property Rows, which returns a collections of rows that implements IEnumerable:

```
IEnumerable<DataRow> rows = copyFrom.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
```

but if you use a different DataTable class, you'll probably do something similar to cast it to a sequence of DataRow.

An object of class System.Data.DataRow has item properties to access the columns in the row. In your case the column names are oid, idate and amount.

To convert your copyFrom to the sequence of items you want to do the processing on is:

```
var itemsToProcess = copyFrom.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(row => new
    {
        Oid = row["oid"],
        Date = (DateTime)row["idate"],
        Amount = (decimal)row["amount"],
    });
```

I'm not sure, but I assume that column idate contains dates and column amount contains some value. Feel free to use other types if your columns contain other types.

If your columns contain strings, convert them to the proper items using Parse:

```
var itemsToProcess = copyFrom.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(row => new
    {
        Id = (string)row["oid"],
        Date = DateTime.Parse( (string) row["idate"]),
        Amount = Decimal.Parse (string) row["amount"]),
    });
```

If you are unfamiliar with the lambda expressions. It helped me a lot to read it as follows:

> itemsToProcess is a collection of items, taken from the collection of
>   DataRows, where from each row in this collection we created a new
>   object with three properties: Id = ...; Data = ...; Amount = ...

See

- [Explanation of Standard Linq oerations](http://odetocode.com/articles/739.aspx) for Cast and Select
- [Anonymous Types](http://geekswithblogs.net/BlackRabbitCoder/archive/2012/06/21/c.net-little-wonders-the-joy-of-anonymous-types.aspx)

Now we have a sequence where we can compare dates and sum the amounts.

What you want, is to group all items in this sequence into groups with the same Id and Date. So you want a group where with Id = 00045 and Date = 02/13/2011, and a group with Id = 00045 and date = ,02/14/2011.

For this you use [Enumerable.GroupBy](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx). As the selector (= what have all items in one group in common) you use the combination of Id and Date:

```
var groups = itemsToProcess.GroupBy(item => new
    {Id = item.Id, Data = item.Data} );
```

Now you have groups.

- Each group has a property Key, of a type with two properties: Id and Data.
- Each group **is** a sequence of items from your itemsToProcess collection (so it is an "itemToprocess" with Id / Data / Value properties)
- all items in one group have the same Id and same Data.

So all you have to do is Sum all elements from the sequence in each group.

```
var resultSequence = groups.Select(groupItem => new
{
    Id = groupItem.Key.Id
    Date = groupItem.Key.Date,
    Sum = groupItem.Sum(itemToProcess => itemToProcess.Value,
}
```

So putting it all together into one statement:

```
var resultSequence = copyFrom.Rows.Cast<DataRow>()
    .Select(row => new
    {
        Id = (string)row["oid"],
        Date = DateTime.Parse( (string) row["idate"]),
        Amount = Decimal.Parse (string) row["amount"]),
    })
    .GroupBy (itemToProcess => new
    {
        Id = item.Id,
        Data = item.Data
    });
    .Select(groupItem => new
    {
        Id = groupItem.Key.Id
        Date = groupItem.Key.Date,
        Sum = groupItem.Sum(itemToProcess => itemToProcess.Value,
    });
```

Comment: Isn't the purpose of the `AsEnumerable()` function to make `DataTable` accessible?

[link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable(v=vs.110).aspx)

Is there some benefit to casting a `DataTable` in the way you specified? 

Also, thank you for the additional information! I've had trouble finding useful linq tutorials that weren't either too case specific or very shallow explanations.

Comment: This happens if you don't specify your namespaces. Apparently you are talking about System.Data.DataTableExtensions.AsEnumerable() while I was talking about System.Linq.AsEnumerable, Apparently your AsEnumerable returns an EnumerableRowCollection which implements IEnumerable < TRow >. If you see some (usually fairly old) collection class that implements IEnumerable, and you are certain that all items in the collection are of type MyType, you can make it an IEnumerable < MyType > using Cast < MyType > () as in my example (see System.Linq.Enumerable.Cast)